# Spring MVC - No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

In my work I have a realy big problem with Spring MVC. I have downloaded sample project from our SVN. It contains simple Spring project structure with Maven. Sample project works just fine. Tomcat starts and I see beautiful "Hello World" page (from index.jsp) on `http://localhost:8080/XXX/`.

The problem is, that I want to write a controller to handle for example "/welcome".

So I have written servlet (mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml), updated my web.xml file, added controller. But every time I write "`http://localhost:8080/XXX/welcome`" I get

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/XXX/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

here is my configuration

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="main.java" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";
    }
```

Here is my project structure (for me it's quiet different from what I am used to, but it not depends on me).
http://postimg.org/image/p649rxbjr/

I guess, that the problem is in web.xml (servlet conf), but after searching google i have no working solution. Hope you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in your context (and the corresponding namespace). As such, Spring doesn't register any handlers with your `DispatcherServlet`. You will need to add it.

Comment: i tried this, but i get "The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound." error. What else should i add to servlet?

Comment: @user3062819 That's what I meant by _and the corresponding namespace_. You need to add the `mvc` namespace like you have for `context` and `beans`.

Comment: ok. i added 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd", and now i can use mvc, but same Warning with "no mapping found"

Comment: @user3062819 This might have other consequences eventually on your application. Right now, both your `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` are loading a context from `/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`. You will want to remove the `<context-param>` and `ContextLoaderListener`. You don't currently need them.

Comment: as you suggested i deleted both <context-param> and <listener> from web.xml, but still same problem

Comment: @user Is your `@Controller` somewhere in package `main.java`?

Comment: yes. its in main.java.something.controller. there is a link to project structure image at the bottom of my question

Comment: @user Your project is set up wrong. `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` should be source folders. Your package should be `com.whatever.controller`. `src/main/webapp` should not be a source folder. Similarly, `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources` should be source folders.

Comment: i felt something was wrong with this structure. as i said i got this from SVN (import project) and this is what i got. is there any way to repair this locally? or this is a repository problem? (then i just report to responsible person)

Comment: @user SVN will feed you a directory structure. This is an eclipse issue. You can do the fix manually or right click your project, select Maven and do `Update Maven <something>`. That should automatically reset everything to Maven's conventions.

Comment: many thanks to you! i imported project once more, made some changes and now controller works perfectly (even without earlier suggestions). you made my day man! :)

Comment: @user Glad to hear it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I tried everything. What finally worked was not including the XXX part but just `http://localhost:8080/welcome`